# Mysql - Query for records between months group by each month

Tags: mysql

I have a table from where I need to retrieve data. 
The table has a date field -tbl_date - what i need is, when I select 2010 Jan as from date and 2011 Feb as Todate, it should display all records between these two date, along with individual results for each month group by the month.

Like - The results should display as

2010 Jan  
Record 1 values 
Record 2 Values

2010 Feb  
Record 1 Values 
Record 2 Values

.........

2011 Feb 
Record 1 Values 
Record 2 Values

Can any one help me on this? 
Thank You

Sathish

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, here's an untested solution:

```
SELECT *,
       YEAR(date) as year,
       MONTHNAME(date) as month
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with that. The `GROUP BY` won't have any effect, because you aren't using any aggregate functions (e.g. SUM). And `ORDER BY` will be slow, because the calculated values `year` and `monthNum` aren't indexed. If you order by tbl_date that can use an index to make the query faster.

Comment: @vincebowdren, must have misunderstood the OP with my `GROUP BY` clause - not that it wouldn't have done anything, it would still have grouped them, although that wasn't the requirement. the rest i have no good excuse for. updated!

Answer (score 0):

The query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable 
 WHERE tbl_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate;
```

That gets you the right data, fast (because it can use the index on the tbl_date field). The only tricky point is getting the right values into the `@startdate` and `@enddate` variables. For your example, they need to be `2010-01-01` and `2011-02-28` (i.e. the start of the first month and the end of the last month).

The other point is that the returned data will look like this:

```
Record 1 values from January 2010
Record 2 values from January 2010
Record 3 values from February 2010
Record 3 values from February 2010
Record 4 values from February 2010
Record 4 values from March 2010
```

It doesn't have the month heading rows saying '2010 Jan' and '2010 Feb', breaking up each section. SQL data queries are bad at returning that kind of data (where the main rows have 20 data fields, and these other rows have just one). I'd recommend using an app (e.g. php) to take the data and insert these headers in the display, rather than trying to get them included in the recordset returned from the database.

Comment: Thank You Vince - i was able to find a solution - thank you again!